# Subtract variable when I click again on a row

Tags: html, angular, angularjs

When I click on a row it adds the amount. For example, if I click on the two rows, it adds the amounts (I add an image).

How can I make it so that when I click on one of the rows the amount of the selected row is subtracted?

My HTML:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of articulos; index as i" (click)="total(item.cantidad)">
        <td>{{item.articulo}}</td>
        <td>{{item.cantidad}}</td>
        <td>{{item.recogida}}</td>
    </tr>
    <br>
</tbody>

<div type="button" class="col border border-white border-4" id="other" type="button" routerLink="/entry-order-lines-quantity" style="background-color:rgb(3, 71, 150);">Cantidad {{totalCantidad}} 
</div>
```

My ts:

```
export class EntryOrderLinesComponent implements OnInit {

  articulos = [
    {
      articulo: '385/65X22.5 HANKOOK AH51 160K (3003836)',
      cantidad: 94,
      recogida: '0',
    },
    {
      articulo: '385/65X22.5 HANKOOK TH31 164K (3003309)',
      cantidad: 60,
      recogida: '0',
    },
  ];
  
  totalCantidad: number = 0;

  constructor(private datosService: DatosService, private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  total(cantidad: number) {
    this.totalCantidad += cantidad;
  }
```

[My image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htriX.jpg)

If I select the row, it adds the quantity. I want that when I deselect the row, I subtract the amount.

Thank you

I finally did it like this:

```
                        <tr *ngFor="let item of articulos; index as i" (click)="selectAndCalculateTotal(item)"
                            [ngClass]="{'seleccionada': item.selected, 'noSeleccionada': !item.selected}">
                            <td>{{item.articulo}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.cantidad}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.recogida}}</td>
                        </tr>

My ts:

      selectAndCalculateTotal(item: any) {
        item.selected = !item.selected;
        this.totalCantidad += item.selected ? item.cantidad : -item.cantidad;
      }
```

Comment: wrong approach. Do not add an amount to the sum of a variable. Run a function that calculates the sum of the selected rows. No need for different functions with a more complicated appraoch.

Comment: [tag:AngularJs] **is not the same as** [tag:Angular].  You are likely to get less helpful and/or completely wrong answers when you tag incorrect frameworks in your question.

Comment: @tacoshy Could you tell me how to do it?

Comment: @miriam what claies said is correct. You should specify what version your are working with. I assume you are using Angular with a version number of at least 2.x.x in that case you are NOT using AngularJS

Answer (score 0):

In your `total` function you could update a new list of all selected articles instead of just adding the amount to the total.
Then you can either add or remove the clicked item from the list on Click.

now you can simply map your list of items to the sum of the amounts

```js
...
  
  selectedItems = []
  total(article: any) {
    // find an item in the list with the same Article description 
    // which (hopefully) is an unique identifier and save its index
    const index = selectedItems.findIndex(item => item.articulo === article.articulo);
    if(index !== -1) {          // If the article was found, throw it out
      this.selectedItems.slice(index, 1);
    } else {                    // Otherwise add it
      this.selectedItems.push(article);
    }
  }

  getTotal() {
    return this.selectedItems.reduce((total, entry) => total += entry.cantidad);
  }

...
```

Comment: And what variable do we pass in the html?

I tried to do what you say but it doesn't work

Comment: the "item" itself. What problems to you have and do you get any kind of specific error, so I might improve my answer?

Comment: @Miriam you got any updates for us? Is your problem resolved? Is there a way for me to improve my answer?

Comment: @Miriam rather than including the answer in your question you should open an Answer. That way future visiter of this question have a higher propability of finding the answer they are looking for. Also please rate any responses that helped in your pursuit of knowledge :)